# Use variable content for declaration

Tags: variables, object, lua, declaration

I'm creating objects from a class and these objects shall get their name by userinput.
So I got my constructor and call it like:

```
name = object:new()
```

end everything is fine, when i accept that the objects name is "name".
But I want the object to be named by the content of name.

So this:

```
name = "myObject"
name = object:new()
table.insert(objectlist, name)
```

Ends up in this:

```
objectlist = {name}
```

But I want it to end in:

```
objectlist = {myObject}
```

How can I do this?
Shouldn't be that hard to manage, but i got no clue =(

Comment: if `name` is a string `"myObject"`, then `name:new()` doesn't compile. You should [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: name:new() meant name = object:new()

Comment: Still not clear. `name` assigned to string `"myObject"`, then **overwritten** by `object:new()`, how to get `myObject` in the end? It's gone, with the wind.

Comment: exactly this is my problem. I want to use the content "myObject" as a referend, not the old variablename of the content.

Comment: If you want to assign the new object to a key in the table based on a value in a variable then you can't use `table.insert` and should use `objectlist[name] = object:new()` (but then `objectlist` isn't so much of a "list" as it is a "table"/"dictionary"/"hash").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Lua don't have names; rather, variables represent names that refer to object:

```
a = "asdfasf"
b = a
```

What is the name of that string? It does not have one, but variable `a` refers to the given string object, and so does variable `b`. So the statement

```
objectlist = {myObject}
```

where `myObject` is a user-chosen name for the object created by `new()` does not make sense in Lua. The best you could do is create a global variable with given name, referring to the created object, or put the created object in an associative table.

For example,

```
name = "myObject" -- would be input by user via io.input()
obj = object:new()
objectlist[name] = obj -- allows for objectlist.myObject, if name is as above
_G[name] = obj -- this allows following line to work, if name is as above
```

This allows your script to write:

```
myObject:someMethod()
objectlist.myObject:someMethod()
```

but of course this will only work if the user has chosen "myObject" as the value of `name`, so in practice, you would likely just use

```
local obj = objectlist[name]
obj:someMethod()
```

whenever your script should use the object created by your user.